# Rails 5.1 API + ActiveAdmin + Sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, sidekiq

A have a Rails 5.1 API that is consumed by a Angular Application.
I have integrated ActiveAdmin under /admin route.
And I have also integrated Sidekiq:Web.

I want the Sidekiq:Web to be accesible only by Admin Users (ActiveAdmin Admins), so I added the following lines to my routes:

```
devise_for :admins, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config

ActiveAdmin.routes(self)

authenticate :user, lambda { |u| u.admin? } do
  mount Sidekiq::Web => '/admin/sidekiq'
end
```

When I run my application and try to access /admin/sidekiq I am redirected to "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/user/sign_in" and get the following message:

```
{"errors":["Use POST /sign_in to sign in. GET is not supported."]}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What happens if you first `sign_in` and then visit `/admin/sidekiq`? Does it work this way.

Comment: The /sign_in endpoint if for the angular application sign in (rest api). For the activeAdmin sign_in using /admin/login.
But even if I first sign in /admin/login and then go to /adkin/sidekiq I still get the same error.

Answer (score 2):

I think you use `Admin` table for Active Admin "admins". Therefore you need to also authenticate `admin` users. It's tricky but by default active admin create another table to handle admin users, it's not supposed to be related with your `User` table

```
devise_for :admins, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config

ActiveAdmin.routes(self)

authenticate :admin do
  mount Sidekiq::Web => '/admin/sidekiq'
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Below solution worked for me:

1. In the routes.rb add `mount Sidekiq::Web => '/admin/sidekiq'`
2. And in the active_admin.rb file add the following code:

> ```
> config.namespace :active_admin do |admin|
>   admin.build_menu :default do |menu|
>     menu.add label: 'Sidekiq', url: '/sidekiq', if: proc{ user.method_to_check_if_user_is_admin? }
>   end
> end
> ```